# Element Click Selenium Not Finding Button to Click

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

For the url below, I am trying to click the "1-50" button (which has its own xpath) and then the "51-100," "101-150," etc. buttons (which all share a 2nd xpath), but my code does not seem to be able to click on the button. Anybody able to figure this out? Cheers!

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'www.sec.gov/securities/files/year/'

page = driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

df_appended = []

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
df_appended.append(df)
    
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="ctl00_m_g_00806bcd_0028_4082_9797_52f6f350e592_updatePanelctl00_m_g_00806bcd_0028_4082_9797_52f6f350e592"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a/img').click
time.sleep(2)

for i in range(1,3):
    df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
    df_appended.append(df)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_m_g_00806bcd_0028_4082_9797_52f6f350e592_updatePanelctl00_m_g_00806bcd_0028_4082_9797_52f6f350e592"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a[3]/img').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    
df_appended
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runs fine if you used the a tag.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a').click()
time.sleep(2)

for i in range(1,3):
    df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
    df_appended.append(df)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a[3]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
```